# c programing issue does not name a type

Tags: c

[this is the error that's happening right now and i cant find a way to fix it can someone please help???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGXoo.png)

what can i change to make this little bit of code work i already tried all that i can think and it just doesn't work

```
//função que retorna a media
float calcula_media(float vet[], int tamanho)
{
    int i;
    float somatorio; //acumulador
    int contador; //contador
    float media;
    somatorio=0; //inicializar as variáveis
    contador=0;
    for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++)
    {
        somatorio += vet[i]; //mesmo que somatario = somatrio + vet[i];
        contador++; //mesmo que contador = contador + 1;
    }
    media = somatorio / contador;
    return media; //retorna para a main
}

//chamada da função em main
media = calcula_media(vet, 11);
printf("A media eh: %.2f\n", media);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it written, you have to define `media` in the calling function also.  For example:

```
int main(void)
{
    float media = calcula_media(vet, 11);
    printf("A media eh: %.2f\n", media);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, `media` in `calcula_media` and `main` are different variables.  If you want both functions to access the same variable, you need to make it global.  For example:

```
float media;

float calcula_media(float vet[], int tamanho)
{
    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    ...
}
```